# Not able to connect a rabbitmq docker with appl docker

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I have a simple app (simple.js), written in nodejs,

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var q = 'hello';

    ch.assertQueue(q, {durable: false});
    // Note: on Node 6 Buffer.from(msg) should be used
    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer('Hello World!'));
    console.log(" [x] Sent 'Hello World!'");
  });
setTimeout(function() { conn.close(); process.exit(0) }, 500);
});
```

And I have dockerized it (simple-app). Then I pulled rabbitmq docker from docker hub.
When I try to link these in following manner :

```
docker run -d --name rabbitmq-server rabbitmq:latest
docker build -t simple-app .
docker run -d -P --name myapp --link rabbitmq-server:rabbitmq-server simple-app
docker logs a8789193af523b
```

I get the below mentioned error :

```
/usr/src/server/simple.js:3
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createChannel' of undefined
    at /usr/src/server/simple.js:3:7
    at /usr/src/server/node_modules/amqplib/callback_api.js:16:10
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/server/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connect.js:167:18)
    at Socket.g (events.js:292:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

I have tried many ways in order to resolve :
1. Exposed all ports with -P option using --links
2. Did mapping of specific ports with -p option --links
3. created network with bridge as driver and used that n/w for starting all my dockers.

None of the above methods seem to work, I am continuosly getting same error.
I am trying this on AWS (EC2) .. amazon linux.

Also, if I try to run the simple.js directly on linux, it is successfully connecting to my rabbitmq server (which is dockerized).

Please help me out here !!

Comment: What's err? Ignoring it is swallowing potentially useful info.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createChannel' of undefined , seems amqp.connect is erring.

Comment: No, err. You're getting the error message when you try to access conn. You're ignoring the error given to the calkback.

Comment: I applied "if" condition for err, if (err) { console.log (err) }, but dont know how it is not displaying anything  and directly comes to same "createChannel" error ...

Comment: That's odd; I'd have to play with it to understand what's happening, but hopefully somebody else can help out.

Comment: Thanks for your time Dave! I had a bigger app, which had multiple channels and mongodb. So hence the confusion. I saw err, it was related to connection refused, then in connection string to rabbitmq,in my app ... I gave IP of the running rabbitmq docker. And that worked for me.